# Storing value into Intent without start a new Activity

Tags: java, android, xml, android-intent

I have to retrieve the total number of permits required by the application, and store this value for use in a second Activity, but without letting it open with the intent. I wrote this code.

```
    try {
        PackageInfo packageInfo = getActivity().getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(value2, PackageManager.GET_PERMISSIONS);

        String[] requestedPermissions = packageInfo.requestedPermissions;
        if ( requestedPermissions != null ) {
            for ( i = 0; i < requestedPermissions.length; i++) {
                permissions.append(requestedPermissions[i]+"\n");
                int total = i++;
                Intent intent = new Intent();
                intent.putExtra("totalPermissions",total);

            }
        }
    }
    catch ( PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e ) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

In another PreferenceActivity

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
        if(extras!=null) {
        int tot = extras.getInt("totalPermissions");

permissionsPreference.setSummary(""+tot);
```

In the Summary of Prefence return 0. Why? Where is the error?

Comment: The Intent object you are modifying and the one you are querying appear to be two entirely distinct objects.

Comment: Sorry I pasted the wrong code but the problem is not that. I have now corrected.

Comment: No, you haven't corrected it.  You are creating a new Intent which bares no relation to any other, modifying it, and letting the garbage collector dispose of it.  This will have no effect at all.  You seem to be trying to treat the Intent object as a global singleton; if that is what you want, then read about how to make a global singleton, though beware it may not be the wisest coarse of action.

Answer (score 0):

You are using different key while putting value and getting value from intent, that's why you are getting zero.

Comment: No, that's not the problem anyway.

Answer (score 0):

The two intent are not the same one. You can make a `public static int total;` Modify its value in the first activity, and get its value in the second activity by FirstActivity.total

Comment: Potentially, but beware this can cause some **highly odd behavior**, especially as it interacts with the activity lifecycle, until you fully understand how to manage it.

Comment: Is there any other solutions using Intent?

Comment: You may want to take a look at this: http://developer.android.com/guide/faq/framework.html#3